# Why am I losing audio on VLC when playing HQ videos?

Tags: video, vlc, troubleshooting

I am having a problem with VLC when I play HQ videos (720p and higher): when I try to look for a particular scene (say I am playing a movie and want to get to go to 30 minute mark) the sound goes off. It doesn't happen always but it does happen frequently, and when I loose the sound is only on the video I am playing. I never have this problem on Parole Media Player, so I think something must be misconfiguled on VLC. Does anybody have any idea what could be wrong and how can I fix it?

---

**Update:** Following the advice from `Skuminder`, I ran `vlc -vvv my_video.mp4` and here I present the lines concerning audio of the output I got:

```
[0xae7705b0] faad decoder warning: decoded zero sample
[0x8803d40] main playlist debug: reusing audio output
[0x87f9030] pulse audio output debug: using stereo channel map
[0xaad017c8] main spu text debug: looking for text renderer module matching "any": 3 candidates
[0x87f9030] pulse audio output debug: changed buffer metrics: maxlength=4194304, tlength=46080, prebuf=0, minreq=15360
[0x87f9030] pulse audio output debug: connected to sink alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo
[0x87f9030] main audio output debug: output 'f32l' 48000 Hz Stereo frame=1 samples/8 bytes
[0xaaf06568] main volume debug: looking for audio volume module matching "any": 2 candidates
[0x87f9030] pulse audio output debug: base volume: 65536
[0x87f9030] pulse audio output debug: changing sink 0: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo (Built-in Audio Analog Stereo)


[0xaaf06568] main volume debug: using audio volume module "float_mixer"
[0x87f9030] main audio output debug: input 'f32l' 48000 Hz Stereo frame=1 samples/8 bytes
[0xaaf07a58] main audio filter debug: looking for audio filter module matching "scaletempo": 14 candidates
[0xaaf07a58] scaletempo audio filter debug: format: 48000 rate, 2 nch, 4 bps, fl32
[0xaaf07a58] scaletempo audio filter debug: params: 30 stride, 0.200 overlap, 14 search
[0xaaf07a58] scaletempo audio filter debug: 1.000 scale, 1440.000 stride_in, 1440 stride_out, 1152 standing, 288 overlap, 672 search, 2400 queue, fl32 mode
[0xaaf07a58] main audio filter debug: using audio filter module "scaletempo"
[0x87f9030] main audio output debug: conversion: 'f32l'->'f32l' 48000 Hz->48000 Hz Stereo->Stereo
[0x87f9030] main audio output debug: conversion pipeline complete
[0x87f9030] main audio output debug: conversion: 'f32l'->'f32l' 48000 Hz->48000 Hz Stereo->Stereo
[0x87f9030] main audio output debug: conversion pipeline complete
[0xaaf0f228] main audio resampler debug: looking for audio resampler module matching "any": 3 candidates
[0xaaf0f228] main audio resampler debug: using audio resampler module "samplerate"
[0xae7705b0] main decoder debug: End of audio preroll


[0x87f9030] pulse audio output debug: cannot synchronize start
[0x87f9030] pulse audio output debug: deferring start (30851 us)
[0x87f9030] pulse audio output debug: deferring start (9397 us)
[0x87f9030] pulse audio output warning: starting late (-12465 us)
[0x87f9030] pulse audio output debug: started
[0x87f9030] pulse audio output debug: changing sink 0: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo (Built-in Audio Analog Stereo)


[0x87f9030] pulse audio output debug: underflow
[0xb24024a0] main input debug: Buffering 0%
[0xb24024a0] main input debug: Buffering 0%
[0xb24024a0] main input debug: Buffering 32%
[0xae7705b0] main decoder debug: End of audio preroll
[0x87f9030] pulse audio output debug: underflow
[0xb24024a0] main input debug: Buffering 66%
[0xb24024a0] main input debug: Buffering 99%
[0xb24024a0] main input debug: Stream buffering done (398 ms in 76 ms)


[0x87f9030] pulse audio output debug: underflow
[0xb24024a0] main input debug: Buffering 0%
[0xb24024a0] main input debug: Buffering 0%
[0xb24024a0] main input debug: Buffering 33%
[0xb24024a0] main input debug: Buffering 66%
[0xb24024a0] main input debug: Buffering 99%
[0xb24024a0] main input debug: Stream buffering done (399 ms in 94 ms)
[0xae7705b0] main decoder debug: End of audio preroll
[0x87f9030] pulse audio output debug: underflow


[0x87f9030] pulse audio output debug: underflow
[0xb24024a0] main input debug: Buffering 0%
[0xb24024a0] main input debug: Buffering 0%
[0xb24024a0] main input debug: Buffering 33%
[0xb24024a0] main input debug: Buffering 66%
[0xb24024a0] main input debug: Buffering 99%
[0xb24024a0] main input debug: Stream buffering done (399 ms in 3 ms)
[0xae7705b0] main decoder debug: End of audio preroll
[0x87f9030] pulse audio output debug: underflow


[0x87f9030] pulse audio output debug: underflow
[0xb24024a0] main input debug: Buffering 0%
[0xb24024a0] main input debug: Buffering 0%
[0xb24024a0] main input debug: Buffering 32%
[0xae7705b0] main decoder debug: End of audio preroll
[0x87f9030] pulse audio output debug: underflow
[0xb24024a0] main input debug: Buffering 66%
[0xb24024a0] main input debug: Buffering 99%
[0xb24024a0] main input debug: Stream buffering done (398 ms in 49 ms)
[0xae71ee18] main decoder debug: End of video preroll
[0xae71ee18] main decoder debug: Received first picture
[0xb24024a0] main input debug: Decoder buffering done in 599 ms
[0x87f9030] pulse audio output debug: underflow[0x87f9030] main audio output debug: inserting 27606 zeroes
[0x87f9030] main audio output warning: playback way too early (-575136): playing silence


[0x87f9030] pulse audio output debug: underflow
[0xb24024a0] main input debug: Buffering 0%
[0xb24024a0] main input debug: Buffering 0%
[0xb24024a0] main input debug: Buffering 32%
[0xae7705b0] main decoder debug: End of audio preroll
[0x87f9030] pulse audio output debug: underflow
[0xb24024a0] main input debug: Buffering 66%
[0xb24024a0] main input debug: Buffering 99%
[0xb24024a0] main input debug: Stream buffering done (398 ms in 78 ms)
```

Hope there's something interesting.

Comment: Does the audio come back after a while (some seconds)? Get synced up? Or is it completely lost?

Comment: @Sukminder The audio is completely lost. Sometimes it will come back if I jump to another scene, but not always.

Comment: Have you tried to run VLC from a terminal emulator? Optionally with `-vvv` flag to get very verbose output? Any interesting messages?

Comment: @Sukminder I added some lines of the output in case you want to take a look.

Comment: Hmmm. PA complains and deliver silence. Not sure if it is a PA or VLC issue.  I'm not able to reproduce using VLC revision 2.2.0-0-g1349ef2 and PA 4.0 on a 32-bit system. There are some threads when looking at the error log messages, e.g.: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vlc/+bug/1319233 , https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=735447 , etc. Not a solution, but if none is found you could use ALSA directly, until an update comes along (if there are none already). I'm mainly using mplayer and mpv and have not experienced the issue there.

Answer (score 0):

If VLC is using pulse audio (play the file via command line `vlc --verbose 2 --log-verbose 3 "filename"`) maybe try to go to VLC tools/preferences/audio and use different output module and the device. Then restart VLC, maybe it will show the error, restart again. Maybe lookup for error looking entries from vlc command output on the internet or search/report it to [PA](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pulseaudio/pulseaudio/-/issues/) or other module that the VLC is using.